# Interop C++/C# 0x0000071

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

I would like to call a WPF GUI from C++ program. The GUI open fine but, when i close it, i have the following error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x74ae3e28 in NewRibbon.exe: 0x0000071A: The remote procedure call was canceled, or if a call time-out was specified, the call timed out.
```

To do this, i have developed the following code:

- C# Interfaces

  ```
  namespace WpfForm
  {
      [ComVisible(true)]
      [Guid("38BA38B5-99AA-4564-B1D5-B117CFFF46DB")]
      [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
      public interface IWindows
      {
          [DispId(1)]
          void openWindow();        

          [DispId(2)]
          void close();
      }
  }

  namespace WpfForm
  {
      [Guid("3C324C9B-E5F2-430C-B591-CB9CAF84B2A4")]
      [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
      public interface IWindowsEvents
      {
      }
  }
  ```
- C# Implementation

  ```
  namespace WpfForm
  {
      [ComVisible(true)]
      [Guid("F53AD10C-CBD4-4E8D-9782-3395E051F414")]
      [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
      [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IWindowsEvents))]
      [ProgId("WpfForm.ManagedWindows")]
      public class ManagedWindows : IWindows
      {
          private WpfForm.MainWindow m_form;
          private WindowInteropHelper wnd;

          [ComVisible(true)]
          public void openWindow()
          {
              try
              {
                  m_form = new WpfForm.MainWindow();
                  m_form.Closing += M_form_Closing;
                  m_form.Closed += M_form_Closed;
                  m_form.ShowInTaskbar = false;

                  m_form.ShowDialog();
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: " + ex.Message);
              }
          }

          [ComVisible(true)]
          public void close()
          {
              m_form.Close();
              m_form = null;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

I open the WPF Form from c++ with this code:

```
HRESULT tmp = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

IWindowsPtr pWindows;
pWindows.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ManagedWindows));

try
{
    pWindows->openWindow();
}
catch (_com_error& ce)
{
    AfxMessageBox((LPCTSTR)ce.ErrorMessage());
}

if ((tmp == S_OK) || (tmp == S_FALSE))
    CoUninitialize();
```

How can i resolve it?

I have searched in the previous questions but i don't have found the resolution to my problem.

Regard,

Luigi